# iOS 17: How to fix a typo in a custom phone number label

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 17.3.1. In the Phone Contacts app, when adding a custom phone number label, I of course made a typo!  How can I fix that?  I can get to the list of custom labels, but other than *selecting* or *deleting* the label there does not appear to be an *edit* mode?

Comment: As far as I have ever been able to see there is no way to edit a custom label in contacts. But as contact custom labels are **short** I have always found it easy enough to delete and re-create.